Missed signal in a Java
Can this code ever lead to missed signal? If yes, then how?
private Object lock = new Object();
private boolean conditionMet = false;

public void waitForCondition() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (!conditionMet) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        // Proceed when condition is met
    }
}

public void signalCondition() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        conditionMet = true;
        lock.notify();
    }
}


The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for might be relevant here, you should check out the volatile keyword.

I believe synchronized would, in fact, mean you don't need volatile here; it establishes the necessary happens-before.

@LouisWasserman you are right, Java Language Spec (I used Java 21 for the link) explicitly mentions volatile as a "more convenient" way "than locking for some purposes" (with example, see 8.3.1.4. volatile Fields)

You need to synchronize to call wait and notify anyway. I don’t think volatile would add any benefit to the code shown here. It looks fine as it is.

The lock field should be final.

You won't lose notification, but leave all but one thread stranded inside wait.
Unless you going to call signalCondition() as many times as number of waiting threads.
To solve it use notifyAll() instead of notify().

I'm going to assume that by "missed signal", you mean "not returning a call to wait() via a call to notify()", i.e. that you don't care whether a notification will be "missed" once the call to waitForCondition() manages to come out of the loop. That said, note that a notifier is only guaranteed to wake up a waiter if the waiter is actually "inside" the call to wait() at the time notify() is called.
Consider what waitForCondition() does:

Strictly speaking, there is "time" between the { and the synchronized -- if the notification occurs in that timeframe, it will be missed. However, considering what you are obviously trying to do, this should not be an issue, since the loop won't even be entered in this case.
The call will acquire the lock. (Remember that, from this time on, no other call may hold the lock until it is relinquished.)
It will check the condition. If conditionMet, it gets to the "proceed" portion, while still holding the lock (and thus ensuring that no other call proceeds). Afterwards, it will exit the synchronized, thus relinquishing the lock, which is what you intended. Otherwise, i.e. if !conditionMet, it will call wait(), which will block (waiting for notification) and (at the same time!) relinquish the lock.
The only way it can come out of the call to wait() (other than something being thrown, which would effectively simply abort the call to waitForCondition()) is for the notification to be received (though possibly without actually having been sent, which is why you correctly used the loop). As it comes out of that call (again, at the very same time), it re-acquires the lock (by way of the lock ownership simply being transferred from the notifier (who must hold it) to the waiter).
Again holding the lock, it reaches the end of the loop and repeats, thus re-checking the condition.

Considering this, we can figure out whether a notification can be missed. Remember that a notifier must hold the lock to notify() (which is why you correctly put the synchronized around that call). In calling notify (as mentioned above), the caller transfers ownership of the lock away from itself (to the caller of wait() that is then allowed to continue), but must re-acquire the lock before the call to notify() returns, as to be justified in still executing within the synchronized block.
Notification can only happen when the call to waitForCondition() does not hold the lock. As we established, the only time this is the case is the exact time that call spends waiting, as the lock is only relinquished when wait() takes effect and must be re-acquired before wait() returns. Ergo, the notification cannot be missed, since the only time notify() can take effect is when the other call does not hold the lock, which is only when wait() is in effect.
That said, there are some caveats:

I've covered this before, but just as a reminder: Never forget that wait() might return (or maybe not return as such, but stop waiting, which may or may not represent an even bigger issue) without a corresponding notify()/notifyAll(). Therefore, always double-check (as which the conditionMet check) if the wake-up was justified.
Also covered, but bears repeating: All calls to wait()/notify()/notifyAll() must hold the lock when called (which is exactly to prevent missed signals), will relinquish the lock as they take effect, and must re-acquire the lock as they stop taking effect. (Though again, all of these semantics are explicitly designed to make the code you posted work as intended.)
InterruptedException is a tricky thing. In this case, it's probably fine, but generally speaking, always consider what you actually want to do if interrupted. Abort? Try again? If so, try again from where? Check a condition before you try again?
I'm fairly positive that the compiler is "allowed" to assume that, within waitForCondition(), the value of conditionMet does not change unless assigned (which is it not). Ergo, it could, in theory, generate code that loads the value once and then uses the cached value thereafter, thus getting calls to the method stuck in an infinite loop. Statements to the contrary seem to be about methods themselves declared synchronized, which yours are not. Therefore, I would recommend declaring conditionMet to be volatile after all, since I don't see how the compiler could figure this one out. This is essentially the whole point of volatile: To tell the compiler not to assume that no assignment equals no change, but to re-fetch the value on every access. See also Happens-before Order.
As has been stated before, notify() only wakes up one waiter. If there can be more than one waiter and you intend to wake them all up, use notifyAll() instead. Note that this will only make them all stop waiting, but they still all must re-acquire the lock (and only one can hold it at a time) before their respective calls to wait() will return.

